# Store predefined information (independent from source) in target's field with Feed importer

Tags: entities, feeds

I'm quite new to Drupal, but I'm fascinated of it since I started to learn it.

However, I've a specific problem which I'm trying to solve since a few hours and so I thought to ask for help.

I use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import press releases from several companies. So, I've for every company an individual "Feed importer" that imports press releases to a content type "Press release". I've also a content type "Company" that contains information about the company. My problem is that I want to add the company to the press release's field "Company" (Entity Reference). But, unfortunately, I don't manage it because it is only possible to add information that is imported, i.e. in the mapping I can only assign information of the source that is stored in a field of the target. But I want to store a predefined information ("Company") in a field of the target.

Example: I've a Feed Importer for the RSS Feed of Siemens and everytime a feed is imported I want that the field "Company" of the content type "Press release" is filled with "Siemens". That's all!

Thanks for your help!